# native javascript use innerHTML to append element

Tags: javascript

everyone.

I encounter problem that performence worse.I make the table and want to insert over 5000 rows, therefore I choose jquery `append()` to insert to table.

**jquery with append()**

```
  let nativeTable = $("#mainScrollPage");
  let allhtml = "";

  for (var key =0;key<5100;key++) {
    var headName = "<td class='tableData '>a</td>";
    var htmlReceive = "<td class='tableData'>b</td>";
    var htmlRead = "<td class='tableData'>c</td>";
    var htmlResearch = "<td class='tableData'>d</td>";
    var htmlVoice = "<td class='tableData'>e</td>";
    var html = "<tr class='tableRow'>" + headName + htmlReceive + htmlRead + htmlResearch + htmlVoice + "</tr>";
    allhtml += html;
  }

  nativeTable.append(allhtml);
```

`append()` great work in laptop.But in mobile device,it would got lag when mobile was rendered table.So I found the native way to insert.

**native Javascript**

```
  let nativeTable = document.getElementById("mainScrollPage");
  let allhtml = "";

  for (var key =0;key<5100;key++) {
    var headName = "<td class='tableData '>a</td>";
    var htmlReceive = "<td class='tableData'>b</td>";
    var htmlRead = "<td class='tableData'>c</td>";
    var htmlResearch = "<td class='tableData'>d</td>";
    var htmlVoice = "<td class='tableData'>e</td>";
    var html = "<tr class='tableRow'>" + headName + htmlReceive + htmlRead + htmlResearch + htmlVoice + "</tr>";
    allhtml += html;
  }

  nativeTable.innerHTML = (allhtml);
```

I use text-tag instead of creating `document.createelement` because `console.time` use tag directly is faster than creating a element that append to DOM.

Unfortunately,it better than performance of jquery,it still got lag in nativeJS.
Devices are `Xiaomi 2` and `iphone 6s`.Any ideas?

Comment: 5000 rows seems to be a lot of data to render. You might want to look at infinite scroll tables instead. Loading what is only seen.

Comment: Yeah that loop with 500 iterations and the data rendering is too much to not get at least a hiccup.

Comment: you need to redesign your table to boot up your code performance . There is not many people to insert that much data in html. Lazyload design (infinite scroll) may help you

Comment: If the lag is really long then infinite scroll tables, as suggested by @A.Lau would be the way to go, Another option is to "psychologically" solve it with a progress indicator or using a timer to show it in the process of being built

Comment: You can not even look at 5k rows on a mobile device. You need paging....

Comment: using innerHTML like this is going to result in extremely poor performance ... `.insertAdjacentHTML` method is a better option for adding HTML strings to an element

Comment: lazy loading seems the best way!I would redesign my table.thanks for al!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out 
HTML :

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header tableData</th>
        <th>Header tableData</th>
        <th>Header tableData</th>
        <th>Header tableData</th>
        <th>Header tableData</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="append">
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Javascript :

```
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){

        if(typeof sessionStorage.firstrows=='undefined'){
            sessionStorage.firstrows=0; //first
        }else{
            sessionStorage.firstrows=0;
        }
        if(typeof sessionStorage.lastrows=='undefined'){
            sessionStorage.lastrows=100; //LIMIT
        }else{
            sessionStorage.lastrows=100;//LIMIT
        }

        viewdata(sessionStorage.firstrows,sessionStorage.lastrows);

        window.onscroll = function(ev) {
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                viewdata(sessionStorage.firstrows,sessionStorage.lastrows);
            }
        };

        function viewdata(firstrows,lastrows){  

            //##### AJAX HERE


           //---- Do pull the data already in the Limit ----


            //##### END AJAX 

           //## Callback function from ajax
            var count_row = 5000; //Amount of data
            var tbody = document.getElementById('append');

            if(lastrows > count_row){
                last_= count_row;
            }else{
                last_= lastrows;
                alert("Append New Row ("+sessionStorage.firstrows+" To "+sessionStorage.lastrows+")");
            }
            for (key =firstrows;key<last_;key++) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                var html = "";
                    tr.setAttribute("class", 'tableRow');
                    html += "<td class='tableData'>"+key+"</td>";
                    html += "<td class='tableData'>b</td>";
                    html += "<td class='tableData'>c</td>";
                    html += "<td class='tableData'>d</td>";
                    html += "<td class='tableData'>e</td>";
                tr.innerHTML = html;
                tbody.appendChild(tr); //append to tbody
            }
            if(lastrows > count_row){
                alert("END");
            }else{
                sessionStorage.firstrows = last_;
                sessionStorage.lastrows = (parseInt(last_)+100);
            }
        }
    });
```